# Upgrade openssl in Docker

Tags: docker, openssl

I have a docker container that has `OpenSSL 1.1.1k`. I want to upgrade openssl package to `openssl-1.1.1l`. I try update it in `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM php:7.4.21-fpm-alpine3.13

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    openssl

...
```

But after rebuild my container, `openssl` version is still `1.1.1k`

How can I upgrade openssl version ?

**UPD:**
Command `apk --update list | grep -E ^openssl-1` in my docker container shows me the following:

```
openssl-1.1.1k-r0 x86_64 {openssl} (OpenSSL) [installed]
openssl-1.1.1s-r0 x86_64 {openssl} (OpenSSL) [upgradable from: openssl-1.1.1k-r0]
openssl-1.0.2u-r0 x86_64 {openssl} (openssl)
```

Also, my `Dockerfile` has:

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
apk add --no-cache libcrypto1.0 libssl1.0 \
```

But, there are no openssl 1.1.1 packages for alpine 3.8. [See](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openssl&branch=v3.8)

So, my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM php:7.4.21-fpm-alpine3.13

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .ext-deps \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    git \
    libzip-dev unzip

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle openssl


# Add openssl dependencies for wkhtmltopdf
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --no-cache libcrypto1.0 libssl1.0
```

What should i do in this case ?

Comment: Have you tested the upgrade by running the commands in the container? It's possible that the repository doesn't have that version available, what does `apk --update list | grep -E ^openssl-1` show?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, please, see UPD section in my question.

Comment: Alpine Linux 3.13's [support status](https://alpinelinux.org/releases/) is "on request"; it may not automatically get security fixes for things like OpenSSL.  Can you use a base image with a newer underlying Linux distribution?

Comment: Try `apk upgrade -U openssl`. That works for me.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you tell me how to find such a distribution ? I tried to explore image layers of php:7.4.21-fpm-alpine3.13, but didn't see anything that would say about openssl .

Comment: If you look on the [Docker Hub `php` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) there is a link to ["supported tags"](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php/README.md#supported-tags-and-respective-dockerfile-links) that lists the currently-supported versions of the image.  You might also need to update the language interpreter, looking at that list.

Comment: @HansKilian thx for your answer, but, unfortunately, it didn't help me, but `apk update && apk upgrade openssl` works for me, if I run it in container. Is it ok to leave it in a Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the `RUN apk update && apk upgrade openssl` command to the `Dockerfile` and rebuilt my container.

Comment: `RUN apk update && apk upgrade` is not efficient. The correct command is `RUN apk upgrade --no-cache`. See stackoverflow.com/a/76440791/685806